# I hate my cat, how can I get rid of it?

Tags: starbound

The cat on my ship annoys me, as it keeps following me and, when it does, it parks itself in front of what I want to interact with, thus preventing me from doing so unless I move the mouse away from it.

Something like this is a pain with the shiplocker, because here it sits and covers most of the shiplocker and there's only a tiny bit I can check before my mouse is off it. More annoyingly, it sometimes parks itself at the flight control and I can't even access it.

How can I get rid of my cat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modding, it's impossible.

However, with the [Purchasable Pets](https://community.playstarbound.com/resources/purchasable-pets.2854/) mod, default pets (the one that spawned with your ship, depending on your race) are removed from the game when you start a new character. Instead, they can be purchased from the **Infinity Express** at the **Outpost**.

You can also remove existing pets with the **Pet Trap** item it (the mod) introduces.